# How to monitor ejb deployments in jboss6

Tags: jboss, jmx, jboss6.x

In Jboss4, I used to have an MDB listening to deployment messages for dynamically registering components in a system. I used the approach described at http://community.jboss.org/wiki/ExampleMinimalNotificationListener.

Apparently, this mechanism doesn't help anymore in JBoss 6.

So how can I get notified after an EJB has been deployed or before it gets undeployed?